# Form-Switch issue with customized Bootstrap 5

Tags: css, sass, safari, bootstrap-5

I am working on a website built on bootstrap 5. Unfortunately I encountered an issue with form switches when using the customized version of Bootstrap 5.1.3

When I include Bootstrap 5.1.3 via CDN the form switches are shown properly.

But when I include my customized version, the form switches revert back to a checkbox in Safari even though I imported all bootstrap components like this:

```
$primary: #00D9E0;
$secondary: #BFFDFF;
$light: #EEEEEE;
$dark: #333333;
$info: #4394B1;
$success: #91C7B1;
$danger: #B33951;
$warning: #E3D081;

@import "../../foundation/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/bootstrap";
```

In Firefox they are still shown correctly.

Am I doing something wrong or do I have to wait for an update?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. open file /scss/forms/_form-check.scss
2. find .form-check-input {
3. go to line 27 (appearance: none;)
4. add these 2 lines:

   ```
   -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
   ```
5. recompile your sass and it should be fine in Safari